# React toggle button only works once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning React Reducer now. I want to build a toggle button that changes a boolean `completed` value to its opposite each time I click the button.

What I have is an array of `states`, each `state` is an object with an `id` and a `completed` value set to be `true` or `false`. Then I loop through `states`, setting each `state` as an `Item` component and display it on screen.

```
// App.js file

import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { AppReducer } from "./AppReducer";
import Item from "./Item";

function App() {
    const initialStates = [
        {
            id: 1,
            completed: false,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            completed: false,
        },
    ];

    const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialStates);

    return (
        <div>
            {states.map((state) => (
                <Item item={state} key={state.id} dispatch={dispatch} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In the `Item` component, I display whether this item is completed or not (`true` or `false`). I set up a `toggle` function on the button to change the `completed` state of the `Item`.

```
// Item.js

import React from "react";

const Item = ({ item, dispatch }) => {
    function setButtonText(isCompleted) {
        return isCompleted ? "True" : "False";
    }

    let text = setButtonText(item.completed);

    function toggle(id){
        dispatch({
            type: 'toggle', 
            payload: id
        })

        text = setButtonText(item.completed);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => toggle(item.id)}>Toggle</button>
            <span>{text}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Item;
```

Here is my reducer function. Basically what I am doing is just loop through the `states` array and locate the `state` by `id`, then set the `completed` value to its opposite one.

```
// AppReducer.js

export const AppReducer = (states, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case "toggle": {

          const newStates = states;
          for (const state of newStates) {
              if (state.id === action.payload) {
                  const next = !state.completed;
                  state.completed = next;
                  break;
              }
          }
          return [...newStates];
      }
      default:
          return states;
  }
};
```

So my problem is that the toggle button only works once. I checked my `AppReducer` function, it did change `completed` to its opposite value, however, every time we `return [...newStates]`, it turned back to its previous value. I am not sure why is that. I appreciate it if you can give it a look and help me.

The code is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-button-cwift?file=/src/AppReducer.js:0-457).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working version forked from your codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-button-forked-jy6jd?file=/src/Item.js

The store value updated successfully. The problem is the way of listening the new item change.
dispatch is a async event, there is no guarantee the updated item will be available right after dispatch()

So the 1st thing to do is to monitor `item.completed` change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setText(setButtonText(item.completed));
}, [item.completed]);
```

The 2nd thing is `text = setButtonText(item.completed);`, it will not trigger re-render. Therefore, convert the `text` to state and set it when `item.completed` to allow latest value to be displayed on screen

```
const [text, setText] = useState(setButtonText(item.completed));
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Now I understand why my code is not working. I didn't know dispatch is async.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved your code, just replace your **`AppReducer`** code with below.

```
 export const AppReducer = (states, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "toggle": {
      const updated = states.map((state) =>
        action.payload === state.id ? {
          ...state,
          completed: !state.completed
        } : { ...state }
      );

      return [...updated];
    }
    default:
      return states;
  }
};
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-button-forked-d4it1?file=/src/AppReducer.js)

Comment: @user13030001 Take a look i hope it solved your problem

Comment: Thank you. I like the way you use `.map()`. It does make the code more concise. But I think the reason my code does not work is that dispatch is async like @Mic Fung said.